# Javascript variable input id

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, input, getelementbyid

I want to create several input field with a loop.

```
    idVar[i]= "test"+i;
    document.write('<input type="text" id=idVar[i]>');
```

Instead of different ids, each id is "idVar[i]" instead of "test0","test1",... .
So I can't get the input:

```
 myInput=document.getElementById(idVar[i]);
```

So how can I name the id with a variable?

Comment: `document.write('<input type="text" id="'+idVar[i]+'">');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenate properly:

```
document.write('<input type="text" id="'+idVar[i]+'">');
```